# How to use Enyim's Memcached Client with the Append method?

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim

The value that I'm trying to append to is a string.  I've been able to convert the string to a byte array using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)` and passing that to the `IMemcachedClient`:

**Appending to Memcached (seems fine)**

```
var value = "Some string value that should get appended";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
_memcachedClient.Append(key, new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
```

**Getting appended value from Memcached**

```
var valueAsBase64 = _memcachedClient.Get(key) as string;
var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(valueAsBase64);
var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I see the value returned, and it's a string.  I'm just not sure how to get the value returned back to the string I started off with (now appended).

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was running into was that I simply was initializing the entry with an empty string instead of an empty byte array.  So the return type was a mangled mismash.

The issue came down to the .Append() method not setting an initial value if the key doesn't exist.  I'll look a little more into it to see if there's a way of having it do an initial Put if the key doesn't exist.

This works though:

```
var bytes = (byte[])_cache.Get(key);
var value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```